# How to make .htaccess RewriteRule without affecting index.php rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using GET requests in my project and I want to rewrite URLs in such a simple way: if I visit `mydomain.com/test` it will request `mydomain.com/get.php?txt=test` on my serverside.

Here is mine .htaccess RewriteRule, it works OK, but problem that it's also affects my index.php, so if I go to main page it starts: `mydomain.com/get.php?txt=test` request and not opening `mydomain.com/index.php` because of my RewriteRule.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)$ get.php?url=$1 [L]
```

I don't want make any extra sublevels in the path like mydomain.com/1/test, it should be on the next level of root.

Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The most common way** is to add conditions to only rewrite non-existing resources (files & folders):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) get.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Another possible approach (which will work fine for **your original request**) is to ignore such rule when `/index.php` is requested:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule (.*) get.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Approach #1 is **highly** recommended and is pretty much universal. But .. *maybe* you serve all resources (images/styles/javascripts/etc) via `get.php` as well (I do not know what your application does and how it works) hence I have provided another approach.

Comment: Thanks first one works great! nice idea to ignore none existing resouces! Thank you one more time!

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

before rewrite rule.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge, your RewriteCond should work well, added as LAzyOne wrote and it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be okay?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteRule (.*)$ get.php?url=$1 [L]
```